# Can I write some data to SD card on Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I checked Windows Phone 8 SDK document, and find that we can read the data from SD card, but we can't write something to it, is my understanding right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get read-only access to specified files on SD cards using the ExternalStorage
 API and ID_CAP_REMOVABLE_STORAGE capability, but you cannot write to this storage.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj720573(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Third party applications cannot write directly to anything outside the application's IsolatedStorage.

Answer (score 0):

UC browser is able to export files to the sd card though. I think they have access to an extended API not available to regular developers, I've tried reaching out to them as to how they did it but so far I have not got a reply. So, yes it is possible, but the clever hack or method implemented by them is not public.
Here is some more information, http://forums.wpcentral.com/windows-phone-8/266236-developers-given-access-sd-card.html

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).