# how to access phone memory from 3rd party application in windows phone 8

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Can somebody please help me here? I have a requirement in windows phone 8, to copy some of my documents into phone memory and then access it in my third-party application installed on device. For devices with SD card slot, I have an option of copying into SD card and then reading files from there, but for devices without SD card, Do we have any option, where my application can access files from the phone memory?

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered here:

[Can I write some data to SD card on Windows Phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13177731/can-i-write-some-data-to-sd-card-on-windows-phone-8)

It tells you how to access memory on an SD card and in other Windows Phone 8 folders, including a Win32 Storage API which can be used to *try* to access files in phone storage that aren't normally available to you.  I'm not sure if this will allow your app access.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402541%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Medialibrary