# Simple SD card compatible database / NoSql solution for Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, windows-phone-8, nosql

Does anyone know of a good database or NoSql engine for Windows Phone 8 that can be used by my app?

I need to be able to open a read-only database file from the SD card. It needs to be able to cope with storing blobs (png images) as I want to use it to provide map tiles for offline use. 100,000's of image tiles will need to be stored in the database.

I've experimented with [SQLite for Windows Phone](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/cd120b42-30f4-446e-8287-45387a4f40b7) via C# wrappers, but I don't seem to be able to get it to work with a database file located on the SD card.

There are limitations with Windows Phone apps accessing files located on an SD card, but it is possible:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/jj720573%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Feedback from a Microsoft employee regarding my difficulties with SQLite:

> Windows Phone apps can read specific file types from the SD card using
>   the Microsoft.Phone.Storage APIs.
>
> I expect that the SQLite implementation for the phone tries to open
>   the database using standard C file API rather than using the Storage
>   objects and so requires that the database be in the Xap or isolated
>   storage and cannot access a database on the SD card (this is
>   definitely the case for SQLite for Windows Store apps).

**Feedback from SQLite SDK community:**

Apparently it should be fairly straight forward to add support to the SQLite SDK for someone with some C++ skills (mine are a bit rusty!):

Replies:

- http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@sqlite.org/msg81059.html
- http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@sqlite.org/msg81060.html

To my original question:

- http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@sqlite.org/msg81055.html

Comment: You can try using JSON/XML. Store PNG images as base64 string. I am not sure how efficient/feasible solution it is.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I don't think it'll work... The file is going to be in the multi-GB's size range so won't be able to load it all in to memory. I'm guessing it will be quite difficult to cherry pick small sections of the text file out to use as needed. Would require some quite complex code I'd imagine to come up with the engine. Then probably need to come up with an index etc. then before you know it I've developed a SQLite ;)

Comment: You cannot write to an SD on Windows Phone.  Access is read-only.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13177731/can-i-write-some-data-to-sd-card-on-windows-phone-8

Comment: That's why I only want read-only access - "I need to be able to open a read-only database file from the SD card".

Comment: Perhaps as a workaround to the SQLite issue, you could pull the images outside of the DB and onto the SD card. You could then copy the DB onto isolated storage and access it there; you could continue to access the images on the SD card. You might have to register your app for the PNG extension (or you could change the extension to something unique to your app - say ".nztopopng" or something similar.

Comment: @chuex - Cheers, some good ideas there! I could let a user download a zip and instruct them to copy the contents to the SD card but I've found this to be problematic in the past with 100,000's of files. I tend to shy away from zips for this now. The database isn't really needed for it's SQL or anything - its just a convenient container to provide 100,000's of files as an easy to download, copy across and use package. The tiles can actually be structured in sub folders in such a way that a database / index isn't really required.

Comment: @Gavin - I'm thinking about creating two files: one json (for example) with simple database containing name,file offset of picture, length in bytes. And the second huge file containing all bytes of merged files. Of course you will have to write your own little program to create such a huge file and manage it. I don't know how fast it would be, but it should probably work: you load json to phone memory and access only that offset you want from SD huge file. A little workaround - just my loose thinking, but maybe will help.

Comment: @Romasz - Thanks for the suggestion. I must admit that I'm starting to think along the same lines. The only concern I have is regarding the index. Loose estimates I'm thinking it'll need to index 400,000 files. Seems a lot to hold in memory on a phone? I'm not sure. I'm going to have to experiment and see if it can work. I'm a little afraid I'm going to hit another one of those Windows Phone OS limitations you don't hear anything about until you start hitting strange exceptions and have to investigate. Guess there's one way to find out...

Comment: @Romasz - Have found this interesting project that I'm hoping I might be able to adapt to my needs - http://openmcdf.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @Gavin looks like what we were thinking about :) I didn't know about that and thank you for the link - it may help one day. I Wonder if it can work with WP SD card - only reading, give a comment when you gave it a try. On the other hand as it is pure C#, you should be able to adapt it, it's rather easier than starting over.

Comment: sqlite on sd card will be either pretty slow or unsafe. you will probably have to trust phone OS to flush all the buffers when phone switches off or user gets anywhere near the sd card. there are some databases optimized for ssd, e.g. something called aerospike YMMV. If you want a good solution, look for log-structured store. cursory search pointed me to RethinkDB, there are surely others too.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb for an embedded solution. it's made by facebook based on earlier google code, so it ought to be pretty good!

Comment: @qarma - Thanks for the suggestions, much appreciated. However non of these (from my quick skim over them) seem to support the ExternalStorageFile class from Microsoft.Phone.Storage APIs for SD cards. Microsoft is incredibly restrictive in how SD cards are accessed through their API. All the usual bog standard IO access methods for Windows OS's don't work with the SD card on Windows Phone unfortunately. Makes options with existing cross-platform solutions quite limited :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was to take [OpenMCDF](http://openmcdf.sourceforge.net/) and adapt it to work on Windows Phone 8. I've made the adapted OpenMCDF-wp8 solution available on GitHub: https://github.com/gavinharriss/OpenMCDF-wp8

I've also made my workaround to the Windows Phone 8 bug that prevents Seek() from working correctly with the Stream returned from the ExternalStorageFile class: https://github.com/gavinharriss/ExternalStorageFileWrapper-wp8

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, it sounds like a very different approach would work better.

Your requirements seem to be that the end user is the one responsible for putting the data on the card using their desktop/laptop.  Then plugging the card into the phone.

If that's the case then it seems the best solution would be to provide a regular desktop app that grabs the images in a zip file then performs an unzip operation onto the destination card.  Essentially, the app takes care of the operation.

If you need any meta data about those images, then a json or xml file should be included.

This should be far simpler than dealing with a database on a read only SD card.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - much appreciated. I'm not keen on creating a regular desktop app for Windows, Mac, Linux, etc. in their various flavours for this task - seems like a lot of effort and I don't have access to all the OS's. However, if you read through the comments on the question above - I'm actually looking at adapting openmcdf.sourceforge.net as a potential solution, so only a single file is required that will provide all the map tiles in an efficient manner. I'm currently trying to adapt OpemMCDF to work with Windows Phone - still experimenting at present though.