# How to write txt file in windows app store?

Tags: c#, windows, microsoft-metro, windows-store

i have been searching all night to figure out how to write txt file to a specific location like D:\
i tried the `StreamWriter` and `System.IO.File` which is not included in the app store applications 
with no luck so far 
i would appreciate any help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13177731/can-i-write-some-data-to-sd-card-on-windows-phone-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't write to any location from Windows Store apps because they are sandboxed, you can only write to app's local folder:

```
string text = "Hello, world";

StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("data.txt");

if (file != null)
{
    await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, text);
}
```

Comment: i found out using the WriteTextAsync that i can write to documents folder which is good enough for me write now

Answer (score 1):

You might want to checkout [FileIO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileio.aspx) class, more specifically [Writetextasync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701508.aspx) method for writing text files.