# Is there any way to copy Files from Asset folder to SD card in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Please let me know if any method is available for copying files from Asset folder to SD-Card in windows Mobile 8.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I write some data to SD card on Windows Phone 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13177731/can-i-write-some-data-to-sd-card-on-windows-phone-8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now we have no way to do this. But if you upgrade to **WP8.1** you can do this

**Update: Windows Phone 8.1 Now lets you install aps to SD card and move them from Phone to SD card as well. Find out how you can do that after updating to Windows Phone 8.1. It is also possible to install apps from SD card and phone storage**

kindly check the following link

http://www.wpxbox.com/guide-to-manage-sd-card-on-windows-phone/

http://www.wpxbox.com/move-apps-sd-card-windows-phone-8-1-perfromance/

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for previous versions of WP. However you're right in 8.1 case.